# Pass local variable over here-document

Tags: linux, shell, here-document

I have a shell script which does couple of jobs with a here-document. But, we are unable to get the variable expanded on remote host.

```
USER=prod

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t <app_host> << SSHEOF
ps -aux |grep $USER
grep -A10 $USER /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
SSHEOF
```

1. The first job is working fine.
2. The second job failing and says `grep: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Well, the file might simply not be there. You should check it. I don't see how this has anything to do with passing variables in a here-document.  The `$USER` string would be expanded on the local side of the `ssh` connection though, and it's unclear whether this is intentional or not. (it would not matter in relation to the error though).  Also note that the `USER` variable is special in some shells and will have the username of the current user in it.  Use another variable name, for example `user`.

Comment: Ah, I now see you're setting `USER` at the top.  Ok, I would still have used `user` or something similar (lower case).  Again, the error comes from not finding the file on the remote system though.

Comment: So the 2nd server is not an Apache server, the user has not rights to that directory, or it is from another distro like Debian and has the Apache configuration somewhere else. However the question is fairly broad, lacks technical elements and just allow to throw a crude guess. It is not good being running automated scripts on that way if you do not know 100% well what you are doing.

Comment: Hi @RuiFRibeiro, httpd file exists on remote host as it is our web server. The script runs as root user, grep the 'username', and prints 10 lines after match. Grep works fine but, errors says file not found.

It appears script finding file in my localhost than remote.

Comment: add the hostname command to it to take any doubt

Comment: The error message says that the `httpd.conf` file isn't there at that path. What makes you think the problem is with the variable expansion? Of course, with the here-doc delimiter unquoted, `$USER` would expand on the local side, not the remote one.

Comment: No, the file is _not_ there. Are you running the web server in a chroot? In that case, the path should be relative tho the chroot directory.